# MVC Form Submit Button will Conditionally have OnClick Event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, onclick

Posting a form from .cshtml. If the Email Textbox has the value of "Admin" and the Password TextBox has the value of "12345" I want to include an onclick event on the submit button.

I thought about if/else block but what to place in the if condition below where you see question mark (?):

```
<form class="fvalidate" action="/entry" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="Email" class="email required"/>
     <input type="password" name="Sifre" class="required" />
     @if (?)
     {
          <input type="submit" value="LOG IN" class="mTop15" 
          onclick="ibFunc.openBoxOpen('/entry/adv'); return false;" /> 
     }
     else
     {
         <input type="submit" value="LOG IN" class="mTop15" /> 
     }
</form>
```

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: The `@if` is Razor code so it is run on the server when the form is rendered on the page: you can eventually check the Model properties in that if... If you want to check the values that the user entered (since you said "posting") then something has to happen in the Controller too. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Form is posted to ActionMethod called "index" under the "entry" controller. If "admin" logs in, I want to post the form to another action method called adv under the same controller and call "ibFunc.openBoxOpen" javascript function.

Comment: @Roman Apart from calling "ibFunc.openBoxOpen()" javascript function it works fine. Could you possibly update with it and post your answer back please?

Comment: I guess it's better to create the logic in your action.

Comment: OK but how can I call the "ibFunc.openBoxOpen()" js function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the flow of the application and what fires when. You seem to be mixing Client and Server side technology.

The flow should be

- Step 1 Submit the form
- Step 2 The controller validates the login and works out whether they are admin or not.
- Step 3 The controller redirects the user to the `/entry` or `/entry/adv` page depending on whether they are an admin or not
- Step 4 On the `/entry` page don't fire the javascript
- Step 4a On the `/entry/adv` page fire the javascript

To answer your question directly. There is nothing you can put in the place of the `?` that will do what you want because that is Razor code which is executed on the server before the user has interacted with the page.

Comment: If the Email in the textbox is "Admin@mycompany.com" all I mention will happen. What's that isadmin thing upthere?

Comment: You seems to be trying to use Razor code to change where the page goes to, but at the point the page loads you don't know who is going to log in so you can't use Razor (serverside code) to change the behaviour of the page. You could use javascript but that might not be very secure. I'd suggest you use the solution that @theLaw has suggested and redirect to a different page once you've validated the user and know who they are.

Comment: Yes but @theLaw telling me to call js function from the action method. Could you give an example? I don't know how

Comment: Rewrote my answer, that should help more. Please don't call me Tommy.

Answer (score 0):

Do the control in POST in the controller, when the "Admin" submit the form make an if then use

```
return RedirectToAction("adv", "entry");
```

Comment: How to call "ibFunc.openBoxOpen()" js function then?

Comment: you'll call the function js on GET of the action adv

Comment: What does that function do? You need to make a distinction between client side (javascript) and server side (asp.net mvc). When you post the form you will be sending data to the server, where it will be validated and then it will send you somewhere else. When you arrive on the new page if you need to run some script you need to work out how you'd like to do that.

Comment: That function creates a popup window wrapping the page which otherwise will be seen normally.